# Stop symfony from escaping html from query result

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms

Currently I am using ckEditor with ckFinder in Symfony. When I save a form the HTML is saved (seemingly so) properly in the database. When I query through symfony and retrieve the results, the html tags are removed and replaced. Can I prevent this? Below is an example of what is in the database. I tried putting in what the HTML Shows but the current eidtor translates it

Database shows:

```
<p> Test</p> <p> <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="movie" value="/uploads/flash/test1.flv" /><embed pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" src="/uploads/flash/test1.flv" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed></object></p>
```

Actaul HTML (Note I replaced all ; with __ as the editor was translating it to the the above otherwise):

&lt__p&gt__
 Test&lt__/p&gt__
&lt__p&gt__
 &lt__object classid=&quot__clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000&quot__ codebase=&quot__http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0&quot__&gt__&lt__param name=&quot__quality&quot__ value=&quot__high&quot__ /&gt__&lt__param name=&quot__movie&quot__ value=&quot__/uploads/flash/test1.flv&quot__ /&gt__&lt__embed pluginspage=&quot__http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer&quot__ quality=&quot__high&quot__ src=&quot__/uploads/flash/test1.flv&quot__ type=&quot__application/x-shockwave-flash&quot__&gt__&lt__/embed&gt__&lt__/object&gt__&lt__/p&gt__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must have automatic output escaping turned on and echo the result of your query in a templates I guess. Read [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer) what automatic output escaping is and how the use of the ESC_RAW constant or of the getRaw() method can help you.