# symfony 1.4 interprets and doesnt show html tags using fetchOne() in template

Tags: php, html, escaping, symfony-1.4, html-escape-characters

I have the following setup: php 5.4, symfony 1.4.17, and firefox, ie, chrome.

I have built a simple news module.

- table: `TbNews`
- columns:

  - `id` as primary key
  - `scontent` as a text field for saving the news content. It will have html content inside, saved with CKeditor and its working perfectly.

If I use `fetchOne()` (in template), the html is interpreted before writting the content.

If I use symfony pager (in action, then template) the html is NOT interpreted and I see the HTML tags in the output with the content.
You can see the examples below which shows exactly what Im talking about.

I have read in other topics that for security reasons symfony output escaper automatically converts HTML into "text", and we must use getRawValue on the data to get the original HTML chars.

- [show html tags in template - symfony and CKEDITOR. how safety?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051847/show-html-tags-in-template-symfony-and-ckeditor-how-safety)
- [Stop symfony from escaping html from query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602822/stop-symfony-from-escaping-html-from-query-result)
- [Symfony.com View Layer Output Escaping](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_output_escaping)
- [Symfony sfOutputEscaper method getRawValue()](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfOutputEscaper#method_getrawvalue)

I have some questions:

1. why symfony output escaper is working with symfony pager, and its
   not working if we use `fetchOne()`?
2. how should I use `getRawValue()` in my example below with the symfony
   pager, interpreting the HTML and then showing only the content?
3. Is `getRawValue()` the best option to get only the content written?

**Example code:**

```
//1. fetchOne() outputs content interpreting html before.
//index/templates/indexSuccess.php
//-------------------------------
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('TbNews e')->where('e.id = ?', '1');
$new = $q->fetchOne(); // <p>testcontent</p>\r\n
echo $new['scontent']; 
// output:  testcontent  --- OK, output is not escaped because we are jumping symfony output escaper since we are doing it directly in the action.


//2. Get all news with symfony pager, html tags are not interpreted, html tags are shown.
//index/actions/actions.class.php
//-------------------------------
$app_max_news_in_homepage = 4;
$this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager('TbNews', $app_max_news_in_homepage);
$this->pager->setQuery(Doctrine::getTable('TbNews')->createQuery('a'));
$this->pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
$this->pager->init();

//index/templates/indexSuccess.php 
//--------------------------------
foreach ($pager->getResults() as $new)
{
  echo $new['scontent']; // &lt;p&gt;testcontent&lt;/p&gt;\r\n
}

//output:  <p>testcontent</p>  --- OK, since output is escaped by symfony output escaper since we get data at the action and show it in the template.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first test is wrong.

When you test with `fetchOne()`, you are inside an action. So the content you retrieve from your database and the one you displayed (with `echo`) isn't escaped because it's not send to the template.

When you perform your second test, you retrieve the content from the action and display the result inside the template. In this case, the content is escaped by `sfOutputEscaper`. If you make the first test and then try to display the content in your template, you'll see that the html is escaped.

```
// in actions
$this->new = $q->fetchOne();

// in template
echo $new['scontent'];

// result-> &lt;p&gt;testcontent&lt;/p&gt;\r\n
```

If you have activated `escaping_strategy` & `escaping_method` inside your `apps/[app_name]/config/settings.yml`, every thing that will be given to the template will be escaped.

When I want to display a html content which has been escaped, I usually use the `unescape` method from the `sfOutputEscaper`. In your case:

```
foreach ($pager->getResults() as $new)
{
  echo sfOutputEscaper::unescape($new['scontent']);
}
```

another option (said by [Michal Trojanowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712294/michal-trojanowski)):

```
foreach ($pager->getResults()->getRawValue() as $new)
{
  echo $new['scontent'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer j0k, gonna read it very slow but I think that you solved my questions :)

Comment: The `sfOutputEscaper` has also a method `getRawValues()` which can be useful here :) Try `$pager->getResults()->getRawValues()` and then `echo $new['content']` will show unescaped values.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Yes you are totally right about my error, since In my first code with fetchOne() I am directly using it in the template instead of calling it from an action (added that info in my post). And as you have shown, it should be also escaped if done right from the action. Gonna test a bit more and add your solution to see if it works, ty :)

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski I wasn't aware of the `getRawValues()` thanks :) [edit] where did you see this method? I can't find it.

Comment: @j0k I wasn't aware of the static `unescape()` - I guess every day we learn something new :) Or we should read the documentation with  more attention ;)

Comment: hehe yes, this forum and people here are amazing, learned too much today :D

Comment: Just tested: getRawValue(). Works without the final 's' --  $pager->getResults()->getRawValue() as $new

http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfOutputEscaper#method_getrawvalue

Comment: saw another way here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony-users/MUznQHbgPYI

Comment: @xtrm I think it might depends on the [`escaping_method`](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_escaping_method) you'll use.